# Как получить устойчивую ссылку на контроллер java FXML приложения

Tags: java, javafx

Имею общий контроллер, с которого хочу получить ссылку на контроллер внутреннего элемента сцены, привожу код класса:

```
public class RootViewController {

    private DocumentTableOverviewController documentController;

    private Stage primaryStage;

    private BorderPane rootPane;

    private ObservableList<RailroadDocument> documentList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void initController(){
        initRootPanel();
        initDocumentPanel();
    }

    private void initDocumentPanel(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(RootViewController.class.getResource("components/DocumentTableOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane docTable = (AnchorPane)loader.load();
            rootPane.setCenter(docTable);

            documentController = loader.getController();
        //Вставил задержку, чтобы убедиться что ссылка активна
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){

                    }
                    System.out.println(documentController);// ссылка активна != null
                }
            }).start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    private void initRootPanel(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(RootViewController.class.getResource("RootView.fxml"));
            rootPane = (BorderPane)loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Метод привязан к кнопке test приложения
    @FXML
    public void testButtonAction(){
        System.out.println(documentController);//Ссылка == null
    }
}
```

при вызове метода `testButtonAction()` ссылка нулевая. не пойму почему так, ведь специально в методе инициализации поставил `sleep` на 2 сек чтобы убедиться что ссылка остается активна. Такое чувство что метод `testButtonAction()` выполняется в другом приложении, в котором `documentController == null;`

Comment: добавьте код, где она становится null

Comment: //Метод привязан к кнопке test приложения
@FXML
public void testButtonAction(){
    System.out.println(documentController);//Ссылка == null
}

Comment: попробуйте добавить в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: Нашел ошибку, ссылка, которую использует метод test на экземпляр класса RootViewController и экземпляр класса new RootViewController() это два разных элемента. до конца не разобрался как создаются экземпляры класса во время инициализации javaFX application, в этом и возникла проблемка.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку вся загвоздка была в следующем:
методе:

```
    private void initRootPanel(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(RootViewController.class.getResource("RootView.fxml"));
        rootPane = (BorderPane)loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Во время выполнения кода создается новый экземпляр класса RootViewController, ничем не связанный с экземпляром класса, в котором выполняется код, к примеру при создании new RootViewController() и дальнейшей инициализации панели c помощью метода initRootPanel(); в системе будет запущено два экземпляра класса RootViewController, один в конструкторе, другой через метод FXMLLoader.load().getController();

Comment: Молодец. Чтобы это стало похоже на ответ, кроме описания ошибки, стоило только добавить, что решением является удаление этого метода `initRootPanel()` из кода контроллера.

Comment: [Отметьте ответ верным, получите +2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/291565)